# is there a way where multiple threads can add to same list object?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, concurrency, threadpool

I am building an application where i need to create a shared ArrayList object. Its a multi-threaded env, so all the thread should write to same list.

I tried to create a list object and pass to executorservice, but this would create multiple copies of same list and at the end I see only 1 item added in the list.

**Note: I only care about writing to list asynchronously. My read is synchronized.**

```
public class main{
      public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        ExecutorService taskExec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(count); 
        List<JsonDocument> documents = new ArrayList<JsonDocument>();

        // this seems to be incorrect
        taskExec.submit(new test(documents, size));
    }
}

class test implements Runnable{

// this class will add JsonDocuments to list object

}
```

How can i make all threads use/write to same List object ?

I am new to multi-threading, any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Update: I tried using Collections.syncronizedList but its still not working for me.. may be i am not using it correctly

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        List<JsonDocument> documents = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<JsonDocument>());

        ExecutorService taskExec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4); 

        taskExec.submit(new test(documents, size));

        for (JsonDocument json : documents) {
            System.out.println(json.toString());
        }


        while(!taskExec.isTerminated()) {
            taskExec.shutdown();
        }

    }
}

    class test implements Runnable {

        int size;
        List<JsonDocument> doc;

        createJson(List<JsonDocument> doc, int size){
            this.size = size;
            this.doc = doc;
        }

        public void run() {

            Hashtable<String, String> ht = new Hashtable<String, String>();

            for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
                ht.put("key"+i, "key"+i);
            }

            String jsonString = JsonObject.from(ht).toString();

            doc.add(new JsonDoc);

        }
}
```

Please correct me here.

Comment: `synchronized`, object locks, monitor locks, [`Collections.synchronizedList `](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)) - Maybe you should start by looking at the [Concurrency trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: Everywhere i read, it only mentions about reading from list asynchronously, but my write is async not read.

Comment: Writing to a list asynchronously works exactly the same as reading asynchronously.  Look more carefully at the example, notice that it increments a variable.  That's a write. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Comment: What about ConcurrentHashMap?

Comment: What is "still not working for me"? Does it not add? Add only some entries? The code itself won't compile since `size ` is not defined. Please post actual code.

Answer (score 2):

`Collections.syncronizedList` should do the job, but there are some problems with your code:

```
    taskExec.submit(new test(documents, size));

    for (JsonDocument json : documents) {
        System.out.println(json.toString());
    }


    while(!taskExec.isTerminated()) {
        taskExec.shutdown();
    }
```

1. You submit the runnables but you do not wait for termination before
       printing the list
2. `while(!taskExec.isTerminated())` is not the
       proper way to wait for termination

Here is the modified code:

```
    taskExec.submit(new test(documents, size));

    taskExec.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);// wait a minute for termination

    for (JsonDocument json : documents) {
        System.out.println(json.toString());
    }

    // This should be inside a finally block
    taskExec.shutdown();
```

Answer (score 1):

`for-loop` is dependent on the operation performed by threads. You must wait for all threads to complete the execution.  You can use `taskExec.awaitTermination` suggested by Eugen. But it's hard to come up with the `awaitTermination` timeout time, you can pass some large value but the solution will not scale well.

**If you are on java 8 or later version, use `CompletableFuture`:**

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(new test(documents, size), taskExec2)
  .thenAccept(documents -> documents.forEach(doc -> System.out.print(doc.toString())));
```

If you are on java 7, you can use `Future`

```
Future<Void> future = taskExec.submit(new test(documents, size));
submit.get();  // blocking operation
// your logic for-loop etc.
```

test class:

```
class test implements Callable<Void> {
   // constructor etc.

    public Void call() {    
       // your business logic

       return null;
    }
}
```

Note that, 
the result of synchronizedList is "synchronized" but not "concurrent". One fundamental issue that many List operations which are index-based - are themselves not atomic and need to be part of a larger mutual exclusion construct.